# Unsplash API Control Image Quality

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

Is it possible to control the quality of the image embedded on the web using Unsplash API or any other way? As you can see in the example below, the image embedded is not clear and blurry while the original image is in a good state.

Original Image link: https://unsplash.com/photos/MDZAbQApcKY

Example of embedding the image above by their API:

```css
#test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/MDZAbQApcKY");
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is not in unsplash but in the `background-size: cover` because the image gets scaled and stretched to fit the container hence the quality difference.

Comment: @zhulien It makes sense, but how do I fix it?

Comment: @zhulien Actually if I can control the quality embedded then the `background-size: cover` shouldn't have any problem because the image is big enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unsplash Documentation](https://unsplash.com/documentation)

Unpslash supports the following parameters:

`w, h:`  for adjusting the width and height of a photo
crop: for applying cropping to the photo

`fm:` for converting image format

`auto=format:` for automatically choosing the optimal image format depending on user browser

`q:` for changing the compression quality when using lossy file formats

`fit:` for changing the fit of the image within the specified dimensions

`dpr:` for adjusting the device pixel ratio of the image

```css
#test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1627156863760-f49b81d8ab77?fm=jpg&w=3000&fit=max");
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```